# Extending Session Timeout when user interacts at before the end of Timeout

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session, session-timeout

In MVC application , I have code in js where it starts ticking 3 minutes before session expire. Once user clicks the screen , I try to extend the session timeout somewhat this way.

In web.config: -

```
<sessionState timeout="20" />
```

I have Session Controller to which I do ajax Get to below Action Method when user clicks on screen while 3 minute clock is ticking.

```
[Authorize]
[OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0, VaryByParam = "*")]
public virtual ActionResult Extend()
{           
  Session.Timeout = 20;
  return new EmptyResult();
}
```

The control does come here and executes the above code and exits fine. But actually all of Session variables are flushed out !!! why is that so ?

Also why do i really need to extend session explicitly when the .net itself should be able to extend it as user is still interacting with screen?

if I have to extend explicitly ,how can i extend the session without flushing the Session variables and without user getting and postback and continue the interactions with website where he left off.

Answer (score 0):

Any request by the user back to the application pool should extend session. You don't need to reset. Try taking out Session.Timeout = 20. I think your are blowing away your session with that.